# Value Axis Label change in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to change the label text of the Horizontal Axis of Bar chart IN SSRS 
Tried with `LabelStyle.Format` but not getting proper values

following are the expression i tried

With IIf Case:

```
=IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 0 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", 0, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 1 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 2 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -2, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 3 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -3, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 4 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -4, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 5 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -5, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 6 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -6, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 7 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -7, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 8 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -8, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 9 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -9, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 10 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -10, Today()))),Nothing) OR
IIf(Fields!monthId.Value = 11 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -11, Today()))),Nothing);
```

This is with switch case

```
=switch(Fields!monthId.Value = 0 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", 0, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 1 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 2 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -2, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 3 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -3, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 4 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -4, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 5 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -5, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 6 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -6, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 7 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -7, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 8 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -8, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 9 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -9, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 10 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -10, Today())))
,Fields!monthId.Value = 11 ,MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -11, Today()))))
```

But both giving above result

[image]

But i want out put something like this

[image]

Please let me know what i am missing here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Either expression should work.

Here's what you need.

1. Right-click the horizontal, or x-axis, of the chart, and select Horizontal Axis Properties
2. In the Horizontal Axis Properties dialog box, select Number.
   [image]
3. From the Category list, select Date. From the Type list, select a date format to apply to the x-axis labels.
4. Select Axis Options.
5. In Interval, type 1. In Interval type property, select Months.
   [image]
   [image]